# how to make httppost actionresult bind to only part of the viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following sudo-code

```
class viewModel
{
    public ICollection<modelA> parentModel
    public modelC formModel
}

class modelA
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual Icollection<modelB> {get;set;}
}

class modelB
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SomeString {get;set;}
    public virtual modelA ModelA {get;set;}
}

class modelC
{
    public int ModelAID {get;set;}
    public string SomeString {get;set;}
}
```

So. the view model contains a collection of As. Each A contains a collection of Bs and there is a separate model for posting back as a form: the form will be repeated on the page, once in each instance of A with the A.ID passed in to ModelAID as a hidden field.  Only one form posting is allowed on the page, The id of the form fields are formModel.ModelAID and .formModel.SomeString as they are derived from the non-parent element of the viewModel.

How do I get the ActionResult to bind only to formModel?

```
 [HttpPost]
 Public ActionResult Input(formModel vm)
 {
    ... by default the view model being passed back is full VM, I only want the formModel so the post signature does not match
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
public ActionResult Input([Bind(Prefix = "formModel ")]modelC model)
{

}
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for. For reference I also found this blog post:[link](http://code.lawrab.com/2012/05/using-bind-prefix-in-aspnet-mvc.html) which points out that if you use partial rendering and pass the viewModel part to the template then by default the modelPart name is not populated into the form field ids.  This is something to consider when refactoring the code